# How to make a date column by year in R?

Tags: r, date, time-series

I'm having trouble doing this and I need to because my ggplot x axis is messy. why doesnt the following work:

```
as.Date(c(2000:2012), "%Y")
```

Or is there a easier way to get the x axis to be years, maybe every 4? Adding

```
scale_x_datetime(labels = date_format("%Y"))
```

After my ggplot code returns

```
Error: Invalid input: time_trans works with objects of class POSIXct only
```

Comment: take a look at [`?seq.Date`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/seq.Date.html). Also try something like `as.Date(as.character(c(2000:2012)), "%Y")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
as.Date(paste(2000:2012, "01", "01",sep="-"), format="%Y-%m-%d")
```

You could then format the date as:

```
 format(as.Date(paste(2000:2012, "01", "01",sep="-"), format="%Y-%m-%d"), "%Y" )
```

You could probably use the date argument to the scale function breaks argument and just a sequence of year values:

```
 scale_x_datetime(breaks=as.Date(paste(2000:2012, "01", "01",sep="-"), format="%Y-%m-%d"),
                  labels = as.character(2000:2012)
```

And if you wanted that to be in 4 year intervals perhaps:

```
scale_x_datetime(breaks=as.Date(seq(2000,2012, by=4), "01", "01",sep="-"), format="%Y-%m-%d"),
                  labels = as.character( seq(2000,2012, by=4) )
```

There's a lot of guesswork in this untested code because you didn't offer a "reproducible example".

Comment: What if I just want 2000,2001,2002. I have a 13x28 data set each row is a different year.

Comment: You need to post a reproducible example.